# How to Click the label element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://192.168.0.133/tiyorelease3");    
driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(//label[text() = 'signup']/@for)")).click();    
driver.close();
```

Comment: I want to click the registration button in the above url, please help me

Comment: Please format your code to readable format, add the html and tell what is the problem with what you have.

Comment: You should also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Add the html of the label to the question, the xpath does not seem to be correct. The page is an internal link and not reachable.

Comment: sorry u can try this url : http://ec2-35-154-164-82.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/tiyorelease3/

Comment: <label for="signup" id="select-register"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> REGISTER </label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:-

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://192.168.0.133/tiyorelease3");    
driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[1]/ul/li[2]/label").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

For clicking on the Register section on your given page, you need to click on the Login first using

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();
```

and then wait for some time so that the Registration section is visible. You can then use this

```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('i.fa.fa-file-text')).click();
```

to click on the Register section.

Comment: My bad. The element is wrapped inside a modal window. You need to switch to that modal window.